# Why does this code go into a infinite loop?

Tags: java, algorithm, list, search, linked-list

I have wrote this code, which will do a search for chars in a linkedlist(called ListNode), checking if there are any chars which is in uppercase, and then storing them in a new linkedlist(and then return the new linkedlist). When I do run this code, it goes in a "infinite" loop not returning anything. Why is that? The NodeList does contain some uppercase chars. Here is the code:

```
public static ListNode copyUpperCase(ListNode head) {
    ListNode newListNode = mkEmpty();
    if(head == null){
        throw new ListsException("");
    }else{      
        while(head.next != null){
            if(Character.isUpperCase(head.element)){
                newListNode.element = head.element;         
                head = head.next;
            }
        }
    }
    return newListNode;
}
```

Comment: If `if` statement fails, then you don't update head, so the `while` loop is always testing the same condition.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What if the `head.element` character isn't uppercase?  The `head` is never updated to `head.next`.

Place `head = head.next;` after your `if` block, so it's always executed.